# How can I revoke a PostgreSQL connection access to a database

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, privileges, cloud-sql-proxy

So far I have a user called `test_user` as shown in the image below, this user owns `test_db`:

[image]

I want to revoke the user's privileges from another database I have, let's call it `main_db`.

Revoke all on database `main_db` from `test_user`; why connected as a main_user, who is a member of `{cloudsqlsuperuser}`.

Essentially I just want `main_user` to only have access to `main_db`  and `test_user` to only have access to `test_db`.

So far I ran `revoke privilege all on database gitlabhq_production from test_user`.

But it looks like I am still able to connect directly to the database `main_db` with `test_user` when I run `psql -U test_user -d main_db -h 127.0.0.1 -W`. I expect this to through an error saying user cannot connect, I have also revoked all privileges of `main_user` to `test_db` but looks like I am still able to insert a row into `test_table` which is in `test_db`.

P.S I am using GCP Cloud SQL instance with Postgres 13.

How do I achieve this ?

**UPDATE**

Info related to the main_db, test_db and main_user and _test_user

```
                                                               List of roles
         Role name         |                   Attributes                   |                          Member of                           
---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 main_user                 | Create role, Create DB                         | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 test_user                 |                                                | {}
 

                                                   List of databases
        Name         |       Owner       | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |            Access privileges            
---------------------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------
 main_db             | main_user         | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | =Tc/main_user                          +
                     |                   |          |            |            | main_user=CTc/main_user
 test_db             | test_user         | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | test_user=CTc/test_user
```

Comment: Are you able to run any actual queries as the user? i.e. list the tables?

Comment: i am able to run insert into a table in test_db as main_user ... i dont want this to happen... i should only be able to run that insert as a test_user. isnt that part of an actual query ? correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

All you have to to is to revoke the privileges from `PUBLIC`:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE main_db FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE test_db FROM PUBLIC;
```

Then only the owners of the databases can connect to them.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, i ran REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE test_db FROM PUBLIC; only... however main_user who owns main_db can still insert/select on a table in test_db who is owned by test_user

Comment: Not if the permissions on the database were as you showed in your question.

Comment: yes the persmission for test_db is as i've shown in the example, could it be that it's because main_user is a member of {cloudsqlsuperuser} ?

Comment: Possible. Hard to say, since your question does not show the roles and memberships.

Comment: Hey i have pasted an update for the databases and roles for both users and dbs,

Comment: Thanks. Then there must really be some special magic about `cloudsqlsuperuser`. Since this is a closed source fork of PostgreSQL, I cannot say anything about that. Perhaps remove `main_user` from `cloudsqlsuperuser`.

Comment: yes so removing that membership seem to work, i cant even connect to test_db with main_user anymore.